# Python Distributed Computing (works)

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, pickle, distributed-computing

I'm using an old thread to post new code which attempts to solve the same problem.
What constitutes a secure pickle? [this?](http://docs.python.org/library/crypto.html)

sock.py

```
from socket import socket
from socket import AF_INET
from socket import SOCK_STREAM
from socket import gethostbyname
from socket import gethostname

class SocketServer:
  def __init__(self, port):
    self.sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    self.port = port
  def listen(self, data):
    self.sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", self.port))
    self.sock.listen(len(data))
    while data:
      s = self.sock.accept()[0]
      siz, dat = data.pop()
      s.send(siz)
      s.send(dat)
      s.close()

class Socket:
  def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.connect((host, port))
  def recv(self, size):
    return self.sock.recv(size)
```

pack.py

```
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234586/we-need-to-pickle-any-sort-of-callable
from marshal import dumps as marshal_dumps
from pickle import dumps as pickle_dumps
from struct import pack as struct_pack

class packer:
  def __init__(self):
    self.f = []
  def pack(self, what):
    if type(what) is type(lambda:None):
      self.f = []
      self.f.append(marshal_dumps(what.func_code))
      self.f.append(pickle_dumps(what.func_name))
      self.f.append(pickle_dumps(what.func_defaults))
      self.f.append(pickle_dumps(what.func_closure))
      self.f = pickle_dumps(self.f)
      return (struct_pack('Q', len(self.f)), self.f)
```

unpack.py

```
from types import FunctionType
from pickle import loads as pickle_loads
from marshal import loads as marshal_loads
from struct import unpack as struct_unpack
from struct import calcsize

#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234586/we-need-to-pickle-any-sort-of-callable

class unpacker:
  def __init__(self):
    self.f = []
    self.fcompiled = lambda:None
    self.sizeofsize = calcsize('Q')
  def unpack(self, sock):
    size = struct_unpack('Q', sock.recv(self.sizeofsize))[0]
    self.f = pickle_loads(sock.recv(size))
    a = marshal_loads(self.f[0])
    b = globals() ##
    c = pickle_loads(self.f[1])
    d = pickle_loads(self.f[2])
    e = pickle_loads(self.f[3])
    self.fcompiled = FunctionType(a, b, c, d, e)
    return self.fcompiled
```

test.py

```
from unpack import unpacker
from pack import packer
from sock import SocketServer
from sock import Socket
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

count = 2
port = 4446

def f():
  print 42

def server():
  ss = SocketServer(port)
  pack = packer()
  functions = [pack.pack(f) for nothing in range(count)]
  ss.listen(functions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  Thread(target=server).start()
  sleep(1)
  unpack = unpacker()
  for nothing in range(count):
    print unpack.unpack(Socket("127.0.0.1", port))
```

output:

```
<function f at 0x12917d0>
<function f at 0x12915f0>
```

Comment: could post some example code to test the scripts ? Thanks !

Comment: What line is the error thrown on?

Comment: Remember that any globals that the function use should be recreated at  `unpack.py`.

Comment: And you should not compare the types like in `type(what) is type(lambda:None)`, but instead `isinstance(what, types.FunctionType)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ValueError: insecure string pickle` is raised when your pickle is corrupted. Are you sure you are receiving the entire pickled object in one `sock.recv()` (unpack.py)?

Edit: to avoid this for any size you could do (your `Socket` class would have to support recv to be called with an buffer size argument (i.e

```
 class Socket:
    def recv(self, bufsize):
        return self.sock.recv(bufsize)
```

)):

```
import struct

struct.pack('Q', len(pickled_list))
# Send it, and then send the pickled list.
```

In the receiver program:

```
import struct

length = struct.unpack('Q', sock.recv(struct.calcsize('Q')))[0]
pickled_list = sock.recv(length)
```

'Q' is an `unsigned long long`. For other struct things see [the struct module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html)

Comment: Thank you. The buffer size was too small.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Process objects are designed to be sent over the network. Look at line 256 in multiprocessing/process.py.

```
# We subclass bytes to avoid accidental transmission of auth keys over network.
```

Sounds like there's a good reason to me. If you want to do distributed computing, maybe you should look into a [library designed for that](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing).

Comment: I can use native libraries only. My first choice would be circumnavigation of that security measure, as the implementation is using a private network.

Comment: Looking over the docs, it seems that `multiprocessing` is a clone of `threading` but over different processes, in order to avoid global interpreter lock. I think your options are rolling your own distributed computing library, or convincing management of the importance of open source. ;)