# Calling user-defined function as native | Python

Tags: python, dynamic, load, user-defined-functions

I am building a system which is much like Mathwork's Simulink or Tanner-Spice where the user defines a function using available operators. Then I need to run that function and return the response to the user. I am using Javascript for UI interaction. Internally, the user-defined function (UDF) is captured as a JSON and passed to a Python server that parses this JSON.

My problem is, how to I now run this UDF? I am not worried about malicious users exploiting this ability to hack, because all my users are trusted ones.

One way I thought was to write the UDF onto disk as a python script and then running the commands.getstatusoutput(). The problem here is that the function might expect several inputs, and it is not possible to pass those.

What I am looking for is the ability to dynamically loading a new python file and its functions, and be able to call those.

---

Found a blog post that explains how to do this. I guess the problem was me not using the right keywords to search.

Anyway, David Janes' blog [here](http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2008/11/27/how-to-dynamically-load-python-code/) explains how to dynamically load a python script.

I would still invite you guys to comment and propose if there are better ways of doing what I wanted.

Thanks,
Nik

Comment: Is the UDF a Python callable? If so, you can marshal/pickle it as is done in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234586/we-need-to-pickle-any-sort-of-callable).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ezod. I have never used marshal/pickle, and the basic documentation looks a little involved. It might be useful in my case, though I'll have to go into deeper details to verify it.

Comment: Even if you trust your users, that doesn't mean you can trust input. If you do, you'll leave them and your site open to [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF) exploits and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple class that creates module-like objects out of code strings, files or code objects:

```
class DynamicModule(object):
    def __init__(self, code):
        exec code in self.__dict__
```

Example usage:

```
>>> mod = DynamicModule("""
... def foo(x, y):
...     print x**2 + y
... """)
>>> 
>>> mod.foo(10, 20)
```

Example with a file (assuming `/tmp/hello.py` contains a function called `hello`):

```
>>> mod2 = DynamicModule(open('/tmp/hello.py'))
>>> mod2.hello('World')
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `exec` module for this, since the input is trusted.

`exec` documentation: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec

Documentation excerpt:

`This statement supports dynamic execution of Python code. The first expression should evaluate to either a string, an open file object, or a code object. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed (unless a syntax error occurs). [1] If it is an open file, the file is parsed until EOF and executed. If it is a code object, it is simply executed. In all cases, the code that’s executed is expected to be valid as file input (see section File input).`

However, you should note that when using `exec` you may not use `return` or `yield` statements outside of functions.

Example:

```
your_json_data="def example(arg1,arg2):    print arg1,arg2"
exec(your_json_data)
example("Hello","World")
##Output: "Hello World"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `exec`. Though in my case, this would probably not work. I am running a server (say myserver). It has a certain data structure (say an array) which it wants to pass to a UDF (say `userfunc()`) which is saved in a python file (say `udfile.py`). I want to be able to call `userfunc(array)`. `exec` lets me to only _run_ the `udfile.py` but not _load_ it as a module and call `userfunc` with arguments. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: do you have to save it as a file? you could just `exec` the data straight from the `json` data and you can use it just as you would a module. I will add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To import a Python file with a fixed name that in a `sys.path`:

```
import mod # it can import mod.py file

result = mod.some_function(*args)
```

To import module if its name is in a string:

```
import importlib

m = importlib.import_module("mod")
result = m.some_function(*args)
```

if you have the module's content in a string:

```
ns = {}
exec """

def some_function(a, b):
    return a + b

# other functions, classes or any code
""" in ns

result = ns['some_function'](1, 2)
print result # -> 3
```

If you don't control the input completely then you should execute the above code in a restricted environment e.g., you could send the strings to [a sandboxed pypy interpreter](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html).

#### Python can parse Python

There is [`ast` module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html) which can help you parse and manipulate code in a safe manner, example: [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4279).