# Python multiprocessing with function defined within class

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have defined a python 2.7 file with many different classes.

Within this classes I have defined many different functions which can be called once the class is set to a variable.

Within one of this functions I have defined another function which I would like to use for multiprocessing.

See the "addValue" function example below (this example represents what I would like to achieve)

```
import multiprocessing as mulpro
import numpy
class Scatter():
   def function1():
      ...
   def function2():
      ...
   def addValue(self):
      x = range(10)  #variable which would contain the data
      def targetFunction(Value):
         return (Value + numpy.random.uniform(0,1))
      pool = mulpro.Pool(processes=4)
      print pool.map(targetFunction, x)
```

When I try to run a code close to this example I get this error from the "map" function:

```
 Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Any help please? If there is solution it must follow the "Class" hierarchy seen on the example above...

Comment: Seems like duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821910/how-to-get-around-the-pickling-error-of-python-multiprocessing-without-being-in?rq=1

Comment: Nested classes, functions cannot be pickled.