# Python multiprocessing and M1 - can't pickle function defined at the top level

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, python-multiprocessing

In the toy code below, I am trying to apply the multiprocessing map function to a list, but I'm getting the following error:
`_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function add_function at 0x138e5e200>: attribute lookup add_function on __main__ failed`.

```py
import multiprocessing


def add_function(x):
    return x + 10


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.map(add_function, range(10))

    for i in result:
        print(i)
```

This happens only when I run it on my M1 mac, on my ubuntu VM it runs ok. Any ideas what could be the problem?

I've been looking for why this could be happening, but no success so far. In [Python multiprocessing PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function) it is said that this error can appear when trying to pickle functions that are not defined at the top level, however this is not the case in my example.

Comment: Cannot repro on M2 (sorry, I can't downgrade my chipset!)

Comment: What version of python is it?

Comment: also how are you running this, are you running it through the terminal ? or using what IDE ?

Comment: `This happens only when I run it on my M1 mac, on my ubuntu VM it runs ok.` Might be a consequence of the default start method being different for OSX and Linux. If you add `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')`, right before `with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:` do they fail the same way?

Comment: OS-specific, sure. CPU-specific, absolutely not.

Comment: @NickODell - Tried that, getting the same error

Comment: @roganjosh python 3.10.13

Comment: @AhmedAEK in running this with Pycharm, conda environment

Comment: what happens when you run it through the terminal ?

Comment: ok i think i get it, it's pycharm, you are running it "in console", use the green run on the top right instead of running it in the console.

Comment: @AhmedAEK wow, it runs ok, thanks! Any idea what could be the issue with running it in pycharm?

Comment: python can't run multiprocessing code in "console" (interactive mode), you have to run the script using the green button on the top right which is non-interactive mode.

Comment: instead of `multiprocessing` try `pathos.multiprocessing` which uses a different  serializer ( not pickle ) as this post explains https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821910/how-to-get-around-the-pickling-error-of-python-multiprocessing-without-being-in

Comment: otherwise if your workloads are going to be IO bound more than CPU bound you could also consider using multiprocessing.ThreadPool instead of multiprocessing.Pool

Comment: Thanks everyone, my problem was solved by not running the code in interactive mode (as pycharm’s right-click, run does) as @AhmedAEK mentioned.