# How to save a function as string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, eval

Given the following math function in form of a Python function:

```
import math

def f(x):
    a = x - math.log(x)
    b = x + math.log(x)
    return a / x + b / math.log(x)
```

Is there any way that I can convert this function into a string like

```
expr = '(x - math.log(x)) / x + (x + math.log(x)) / math.log(x)'
```

so that when I want to call the function, I can simply use it by

```
func = lambda x: eval(expr)
print(func(3))
# 4.364513583657809
```

Note that I want to keep `a` and `b` in the original function. In reality, I have a lot more intermediate variables. Also, I am aware `sympy` could do similar tasks, but I would like to know if it is possible to convert the function to string, as it would be much more efficient to store.

Any suggestions?

Comment: store? store where? Saving lambda functions inside variables is not good practise (as you probably know). And you can have a lambda function with multiple parameters, so what's the issue here?

Comment: [but eval is really dangerous....](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) and yes, maybe you're writing all the code that gets `eval`ed, but do you know that you write perfect code?

Comment: Could you give a better idea of intent/desired usecase involving `a` and `b`?

Comment: How do you expect it to work if the function has control structures like loops?

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp Why does it matter? If they don't use `eval()` and just call the function, the same code imperfections will exist.

Comment: `eval()` is only dangerous if you're evaluating source code you don't control.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. It sounds like your *actual* problem is how to store functions. Instead of storing it as a source-code string, which is fraught with problems, consider using an approach like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6234683/5014455

Comment: @Barmar I hear your point; trying to debug an error on an `eval` would be misleading, at best, if it's executing code you wrote somewhere else.

Comment: Or better yet, use the [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) package that implements function object serialization.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The unfortunate thing is, I need to save these function expressions as dictionary keys, which doesn't allow many dtypes

Comment: @ShaunHan huh? Dictionaries don't *have* dtypes ... I think you mean types. And dictionaries can take arbitrarly many types as long as it is hashable. In any case `dill` will produce a `bytes`, which will be perfectly hashable

Comment: Perhaps this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427453/how-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-a-python-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is *already* a string the moment you write it to a file!

If the function is valid Python, you can then just `import` it

```py
from myfile import expr
print(expr(3))  # 4.364513583657809
```

---

**WARNING Do not ever do this**

If you want some *incredibly evil* logic for some reason, you can save your function directly with `inspect.getsource(f)` and then do something like this

```py
>>> fn_body = """def f(x):
...     a = x - math.log(x)
...     b = x + math.log(x)
...     return a / x + b / math.log(x)
... """
>>> eval(f'lambda {fn_body.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]}, _={exec(fn_body)}: {fn_body.split(" ", 1)[-1].split(")")[0]})')(3)
4.364513583657809
```

This works by finding the parts needed to call the function, evaluating the source as one of the args (to smuggle it into your namespace), and then building an anonymous function to call it

Further Caveats

- not remotely maintainable
- extremely fragile
- will clobber or conflict with an existing function with the same name depending on use
- you will still need to `import math` or whatever other libraries
- won't work with default args without more pain
- calling `eval()` first (before creating the `lambda`) will allow you to use `inspect` to get the signature (`.signature()`) and you can combine it with `re` and/or `ast` for a much robust parser, but a 1-liner seemed more exciting
- manages to use both `eval()` *and* `exec()` for an extra helping of evil

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I'm looking for and it works fine. I just want to write some hard-coded scripts to do a certain task at hand, so it is perfectly fine as long as it works.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for a symbolic equation solver!

Sympy's [lambdify feature](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) can do this for you!

```py
>>> fn = sympy.lambdify("x", '(x - log(x)) / x + (x + log(x)) / log(x)')
>>> fn(x=3)
4.364513583657809
```

Caution: this also uses `eval` internally as [**@Joshua Voskamp** warns about in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934412/how-to-save-a-function-as-string-in-python/69934452#comment123623644_69934412)

Comment: He said he knows he can do something similar in sympy.

Comment: But my question is given the Python function, how can I convert it into the string `'(x - log(x)) / x + (x + log(x)) / log(x)'`?

Comment: Ah, the haze of excitement makes reading difficult, still, I suspect from their wording that they may not be aware of Sympy's lambdify feature!

Comment: But where does the string argument to `lambdify` come from? They just have a function.